# Dihedral group understanding

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

I have just started reading [Abstract Algebra](https://www.academia.edu/13527708/Abstract_algebra_Dummit_and_Foote) by Dummit and Foote and I have been stuck on their explanation of dihedral groups.

On page 23 Dihedral Groups there are 3 paragraphs(one paragraph is at beginning of page 24). There the author tries to explain the rotation via permutation of the set of numbers that are assigned to vertices. After that he explains the permutation of rotating the $n$-gon by $1$ step clockwise and says that the permutation is just $1$.

[image]

> Then each symmetry $s$ can be described uniquely by the corresponding permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ where if the symmetry $s$ puts vertex $i$ in the place where vertex $j$ was originally, then $\sigma$ is the permutation sending $i$ to $j$. For instance, if $s$ is a rotation of $2\pi/n$ radians clockwise about the center of the $n$-gon, then $\sigma$ is the permutation sending $i$ to $i+1$, $1 \le i \le n-1$, and $\sigma(n) = 1$.

Can anyone check out those 3 paragraphs and tell me how to understand the author's explanation of dihedral groups?

Comment: This would be a much more reasonable request if you reproduced those paragraphs here :)

Comment: And made your question very specific.  "Explain these three paragraphs" is likely too broad.

Comment: Well specifically, I do not understand the permutations I will edit the question with specific problem.

Comment: They do not say that permutation "is just $1$."  They tell you where $n$ is to map under such a permutation, which is $\sigma(n)=1$.

Comment: So the actual permutation of the set would then be $\{n, 1, 2, 3,...\}$?

Comment: A permutation is a function, not a set.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought permutation of a set is that same set rearranged into a tuple?

Comment: Right, but tuples are usually written with different notation from sets, since tuples are ordered but sets are not.  Permutations are better written in 2-row notation or in cycle notation.  In spirit, you are correct.

Comment: So what is the resulting tuple or whatever after applying the permutation function?

Comment: As a tuple it's $(2,3,  \ldots, n, 1) = (\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \ldots, \sigma(n-1), \sigma(n))$.

Comment: Strictly speaking the question you are asking is about the cyclic group - it becomes the dihedral group once reflections are allowed. It is really worth taking the time to understand this - some is just notation, but there are some key ideas about groups here too.

Comment: Also how to interpret this 'sending $i$ to $i + 1$, $1 \le i \le n-1$'?

Comment: $f(x)=y$ "sends" $x$ to $y$.  This is just ordinary, common function language.

Comment: What does the inequality mean? $1 \le i \le n-1$

Comment: If the original is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then after applying $\sigma$ you get $\{5,1,2,3,4\}$. Here everything is shifted right except the last $5$. It goes to $1$ instead of $6$. You can express this as, when $1\le i \le 4$, we have $\sigma(i) = i+1$ and when $i=5$ we have $\sigma(5)=1$

Comment: I don't understand.  It means that $i$ is an integer between $1$ and $n-1$ inclusive.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the inequality. It just means that every integer that is not $n$ gets incremented?

Comment: Yes just that..

Comment: Integers represent the indices of the objects(vertices of n-gon in your case). You should read that  as `1st object goes to 2nd, 2nd object goes to 3rd,..., last object goes to 1st`

Comment: The formal definition of a permutation of a set $A$ is "a bijection from a set $A$ to itself." You may find this question helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329363/why-does-a-bijection-from-a-set-to-itself-deserve-the-name-permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permutation of a set is not that same set but rearranged. Instead it is the act of rearranging; it is a function from that set to itself. In this example the set is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and the permutation is the function
$$\sigma:\ \{1,\ldots,n\}\ \longrightarrow\ \{1,\ldots,n\}:\ i\ \longmapsto\ \begin{cases}i+1&\text{ if }i\neq n\\1&\text{ if }i=n\end{cases}.$$
That is, te particular permutation described here maps each number to the next number, and the last number to the first. When applied repeatedly, it sends the numbers around in a circle. After $n$ times, we are back to where we started.

This is precisely what happens to the vertices of a regular $n$-gon when rotating by $\tfrac{2\pi}{n}$ degrees, which is what the included pictures intends to illustrate; you can visualize this permutation by imagining this rotation of a regular $n$-gon.